# Authentication for Apache Ignite 2.5

Tags: ignite

I would like to implement authentication for all the nodes of the cluster (client and server should provide username and password to join the cluster). I tried to use the latest version, which the documentation claims to provide authentication, but it doesn't implement it for all the nodes; it's just for the new thin java client.

**First question**: is my understanding correct, or am I missing something?

I also tried to implement the authentication of all the nodes using the GridSecurityProcessor interface, as part of a custom plugin (by following this guide http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/ and other discussions on the public mailing list).

I got the plugin to be recognized by the server node, but I can't wire my implementation of the SecurityCredentialsProvider to Ignite; it seems Ignite doesn't use it. The question is similar to this one: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Custom-SecurityCredentialsProvider-and-SecurityCredentials-td16360.html.

As a consequence, when GridSecurityProcessor.authenticateNode(ClusterNode node, SecurityCredentials cred) is called, cred is null.

**Second question**: How to hook SecurityCredentialsProvider and SecurityCredentials to Ignite, so that it will call the authorizeNode method from my plugin, with these credentials?

Comment: Have you considered using SSL + signed certificates for server-server peer authentication?

Comment: It seems that there's answer for second question on userlist: http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Authentication-for-Apache-Ignite-2-5-tp22565p22576.html

Comment: @alamar thanks for the responses. I don't want to use ssl and even if I wanted, it doesn't resolve the authentication problem, it just provide encrypted communication. So it's not a solution for Ignite node authentication.

Comment: of course SSL provides authentication, it is a prime reason to use SSL at all. Normally, both ends of TLS connection authenticate each other.

Comment: @alamar, I don't understand exactly what you're saying. As I said, I don't need ssl, but I want to get your point. Can you please provide more info on how to implement node authentication using ssl in scenario with multiple ignite nodes (both client and server)? Thanks.

Comment: I don't have such detailed explanation for Apache Ignite, but you can reuse most of the description from Cassandra https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureSSLCertWithCA.html
Basically, you create a CA that only you can have access to, you sign keys of all your nodes, provide trust store to all nodes, and a rogue node will be rejected and has no way of gaining access without a certificate from your CA.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to implement authentication with using the plugin system recommended by the documentation. I followed these steps:

1. Created a class extending the TcpDiscoverySpi and implements DiscoverySpiNodeAuthenticator. In it I pass the SecurityCredentials object as a constructor parameter.

`

```
  public CustomTcpDiscoverySpi(final SecurityCredentials securityCredentials) {
    this.securityCredentials = securityCredentials;
    this.setAuthenticator(this);
  }
```

2. In this class, I override the setNodeAttributes from TcpDiscoverySpi to add the securityCredentials object like this:

`

```
  @Override
  public void setNodeAttributes(final Map<String, Object> attrs, final IgniteProductVersion ver) {
    attrs.put(IgniteNodeAttributes.ATTR_SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, this.securityCredentials);
    super.setNodeAttributes(attrs, ver);
  }
```

3. I also implement the authenticateNode method where I check the SecurityCredentials object of this class with the one received as a parameter on the authenticateNode method. This method returns an implementation of SecurityContext if authentication succeeded or null if not; so you need to implement it as you like. For example to give full access with no authorization, just return true for all the ****operationAllowed methods and return null in subject() method.
4. In IgniteConfiguration, use this class as discoverySpi: cfg.setDiscoverySpi(customTcpDiscoverySpi);